# Searching a 2D Array for all zeroes in a row

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to see if I can find if an entire row in an n x n 2D array is all zeros and I had this code originally but I was told not to use goto. How would I go about taking that out?

```
int first_zero_row = -1;    
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
    if(A[i][j]) goto next;
  }
  first_zero_row = i;
  break;
next:
}
```

Like what is the most efficient way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
int first_zero_row = -1;    
int flag, i, j;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    flag = 1;
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(A[i][j]) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        first_zero_row = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using a fixed zero-array and a system intrinsic `memcmp()`, this is about the simplest I can think of. it probably optimizes down pretty well, though I've not sent to asm-output to verify that.

```
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
    for (j=0; j<n && !A[i][j]; ++j);
    if (j == n)
        break;
}

first_zero_row = (i < n ? i : -1);
```

A VLA-based solution *may* improve performance for sufficiently large `n`, dependent on just how smart the the optimizer is. If the system has reasonably intelligent intrinsics for `memset` and `memcmp` the following *might* perform better than the above:

```
int find_zero_row(int n, int A[n][n])
{
    int zeros[n], i;
    memset(zeros, 0, sizeof(zeros));
    for (i=0;i<n && memcmp(A[i], zeros, sizeof(zeros)); ++i);
    return (i < n ? i : -1);
}
```

Finally, though I realize this is a C question, I'm including the following for anyone remotely interested in a fixed-array C++ solution using a template-function. The following optimizes *substantially* if `std::memcmp` is a well-writin intrinsic:

```
template<int N>
int find_zero_row(int (&A)[N][N])
{
    static const int zeros[N] = {};
    int i=0;
    for (; i<N && std::memcmp(A[i], zeros, sizeof(zeros)); ++i);
    return (i < N ? i : -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int first_zero_row = -1;    
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  first_zero_row = i;
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
    if(A[i][j]) {
       first_zero-row = -1;
       break;
    }
  }
  if (first_zero_row != -1) break;
}
```

Is one possibility off the top of my head

Answer (score -1):

[memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) is faster. Something like

emptyRow[4]={0};
   Rowlen = 4 *sizeof(elem);

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
  if (memcmp(A[i][0], emptyRow, Rowlen))
  {

  }

}
```